# Markers not showing on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to show markers on my map. but it's not showing them.

this is the code I use:

```
var map;
var markers = new Array();

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(27.9881, 86.9253),
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addMarker);
}

function addMarker(event) {
    markers.push(event.latLng);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map
    });

    console.log(markers);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

the console is logging on every click an new coordinate, so the function is called, and coordinates are passed. And I can't really see any problems in the marker code.

So can anyone see the problem?

Comment: Visiting today and i just see that may be removing var from initialize() function will solve it   :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` is a local variable, only visible inside `initialize`.

Use `this` instead of `map` when you set the `map`-property of the marker:

```
function addMarker(event) {
    markers.push(event.latLng);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: this
    });
}
```

**Explanation:**

the callback will be executed in the scope of the object that triggers the event. Here it is the Maps-instance(because the click-listener has been applied  to the map ), `this` will refer to this object inside the callback.

Answer (score 2):

```
markers.push(event.latLng);
```

Here you're pushing the latlng, not the marker.

`markers` is an array variable with global scope, whereas `marker` is a local variable.
In `markers` array you have to insert each inidividual `marker` and then process it.

```
function addMarker(event) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
}
```