# Marker(s) Not Showing on Leaflet Map - Twig Location Array to Leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet, twig, craftcms

I have a template here with my twig/javascript - I am having an issue passing "locations" through my javascript function which is to grab the latitude and longitude coordinates from the array and pass that through to display the map marker(s) on the map which currently do not show up on the map.

Right now, I have no errors and the coordinates are being pulled correctly via Twig and are logging appropriately to the console via

`console.log(locations)` in my script after defining the locations variable:

```
var locations = {{ coords|json_encode|raw }};
```

which outputs in the console as

```
> {lat: "50.41830281867368", lng: "-104.51004534959793"}
    lat: "50.41830281867368"
    lng: "-104.51004534959793"
    > __proto__: Object
```

and it also displays the correct coordinates when using

```
{{ dump(coords) }}
```

my current code in its entirety (HTML/Twig & Scripts) below:

```
  <body>
    {% include '_includes/nav' %}
    <div>
      {% block content %}

      {% endblock %}
      <div class="map-test">
        {% set entries = craft.entries().section('showHomes').all() %}
        {% set coords = {} %}
        {% for post in entries %}
          {% for coord in post.lotInfo %}
            {% if coord.createNewEntry == '1' %}
              {% set coords =
                coords|merge({
                  lat: coord.latitude,
                  lng: coord.longitude
                })
              %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha512QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg=="
      crossorigin=""></script>
    <script>
      var map = L.map('map', { scrollWheelZoom: false }).setView( [50.4205,-104.52], 15, )
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 19, 
      minZoom: 14.5 }).addTo(map)

      var locations = {{ coords|json_encode|raw }};

      function addToMap(locationArray) { 
        [].forEach.call(locationArray, function(location) { 
          var marker = L.marker([{lat:locations.lat,lng:locations.lng}]).addTo(map); 
          }); 
        }
      addToMap(locations); 
      console.log(locations);
    </script>
  </body>
```

So basically everything seems to be working- no errors and the coordinates are outputting in the console when logged, it's just that my javascript function does not seem to be adding the markers to the map which leads me to believe the problem is somewhere with that function and its ability to interpret

```
var marker = L.marker([locations.lat, locations.lng]).addTo(map);
```

I have also tried this variation on the variable marker:

```
var marker = L.marker([{lat:locations.lat,lng:locations.lng}]).addTo(map);
```

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Seems like you are feeding some special Lat/Lng object to your template. Try to extract the primitive coordinates or try to use the `.toJSON()` maps function on coords

Comment: @wp78de You were definitely right in that it is unable to plot the Lat/Lng coordinates because the Twig script its creating an object containing the values and the Javascript function is expecting an Array. At least I am sure that is what it is. Do you have any suggestions on how to adjust the Javascript to accept an object and plot the values?

Comment: Can you manipulate the LatLng object before you pass it into the template?

Comment: Yes, the Twig portion above sitting within the div.map-test is what is looking at the field table and grabbing those values and creating the object {{ coords }}. In what way do you mean manipulate it? - thank you for your quick response btw

Comment: @wp78de I noticed when I console log locations.lat or locations.lng, it correctly outputs the values to the console but when I add them here ```var marker = L.marker([locations.lat, locations.lng]).addTo(map);``` the marker does not output? -> console.log(locations) returns the array containing lat and lng.

Comment: Okay, so the problem now is the marker is not showing? This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/20679955/8291949

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223115/discussion-between-gideon-b-and-wp78de).